# Angular: Change field of parent component from route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

everyone!

I need your help. I have a component in my Angular 10 application, let's name it A.

In this component I have `<router-outlet>` and also routes described in routes.ts file.

What I need is to change variable (field) inside A component by clicking button from some B component, that is route inside `<router-outlet>`. How can I do it?

For example, we can talk about such variant.

A.component.html

```
<B [changeFieldOfA]="func"></B>
```

A.component.ts

```
export class A {
    foo: string = "";
    func() {
        this.foo = "bar";
    }
}
```

Here's everything cool,  cause I can pass function, that changes my A component field to my  component.

But what if I have this variant?:

A.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

routes.ts

```
{path: "b", component: B}
```

I want to call this func(), that belongs to A (and changes its field) inside B, but i can't do it through Input() anymore, cause in router I can't do it.

Comment: I am having a difficult time understanding. is B a child component of A? Or a new routed to component? If you route to B, you are no longer viewing A so you wouldn't be able to change a variable in A.

Comment: Your question has  code description. Actual code is much better.

Comment: maybe there's some other use of angular, but shouldn't you ONLY have the router-outlet in your app.component.html file? I'm not familiar with the idea of an app having multiple router outlets. seems confusing and unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3xadmw) You can use service to communicate between components

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class ShareService  {   
  constructor() { } 
  private paramSource = new BehaviorSubject("");
  sharedData = this.paramSource.asObservable();
  setParam(param:string) { this.paramSource.next(param)}    
}
```

to set in service

```
this.shareService.setParam('Sending param');
```

to get from service

```
 this.shareService.sharedData.subscribe(data=> { this.your_variable=data })
```

constructors like

```
constructor(private shareService: ShareService  ){}
```